# ssl for dokku and digital ocean

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

if i push a new app, called test, to my droplet with dokku on example.com, here's the link:

http://test.example.com

i've seen tutorials on how to add ssl for this specific app. (ie https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Jan/23/blog-tech-stack/).

how might i set up by digital ocean droplet so that every app up push with dokku has ssl enabled? is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to official Dokku [readme](http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/nginx) (v0.2.3):

> **All Subdomains**
>
> To enable TLS connections for all your applications at once you will
>   need a wildcard TLS certificate.
>
> To enable TLS across all apps, copy or symlink the `.crt/.pem` and `.key`
>   files into the `/home/dokku/tls` folder (create this folder if it
>   doesn't exist) as `server.crt` and `server.key` respectively. Then, enable
>   the certificates by editing `/etc/nginx/conf.d/dokku.conf` and
>   uncommenting these two lines (remove the #):
>
> `ssl_certificate /home/dokku/tls/server.crt;`
>
> `ssl_certificate_key /home/dokku/tls/server.key;`
>
> The nginx configuration will need to be reloaded in order for the updated TLS configuration > to be applied.
>   This can be done either via the init system or by re-deploying the
>   application. Once TLS is enabled, the application will be accessible
>   by https:// (redirection from http:// is applied as well).
>
> **Note**: TLS will not be enabled unless the application's VHOST matches
>   the certificate's name. (i.e. if you have a cert for *.example.com TLS
>   won't be enabled for something.example.org or example.net)

Disclaimer: I have not tested this myself, it's just from the official docs.